# v-on:click not working on vue.js no matter what tweaks I do, how can I fix this?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am running vue.js inside express, all works as intended eccept for the click event... It does not do anything, when I click on either button, nothing is fired

the HTML :

```
<div v-on:click="function2">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click.native="testFunction">Function 1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="function2">Function 2</button>
</div>
```

The server

```
app.get('*', async(req, res) => {
const app2 = createSSRApp({
    data (){
        return {
            url: req.url,
            message : 'ok',
            ok : true,
            image : '...'
        }
    },
    methods : {
        testFunction(event){
            this.$emit('click', this.page, event);
        },
        function2(){
            console.log('9')
        }
    },
    template : require('fs').readFileSync('./html/pages/home.html', 'utf-8')
})
const content = await renderToString(app2)

const html = `
        <!DOCTYPE html><script>
        console.log('ooo')
    </script>
        <html lang="en">
        <head><title>Hello</title></head>
        <body>${content}</body>
        </html>
    `
    res.end(html)
})
```

I am using express and ssr.

I even put some inline javascript in the header to check and in the header, it works, but not in the click even

Comment: You didnt read the part at the bottom of the docs, *Now, when running this Node.js script, we can see a static HTML page on localhost:8080. **However, this code is not hydrated: Vue hasn't yet take over the static HTML sent by the server** to turn it into dynamic DOM that can react to client-side data changes. This will be covered in the Client Side Hydration section. see: https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/hydration.html

Comment: the documentation for SSR is sooooo poor... Can someone explain? Because the way it is supposed to be done is different than in vue3 docs

Comment: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/ssr/getting-started.html - This guide is currently under active development ~ use Nuxt if you want simple SSR

Answer (score 1):

You are using `@click` in

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click.native="testFunction">Function 1</button>
```

and you also use `v-on:click` in

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="function2">Function 2</button>
```

So `@click="addTwo"` is the same as `v-on:click="addTwo"`

The Vue.js style guide recommends to not mix them in your project. Use `@` or `v-on` but not both.

Comment: I first tried only with v-on.... then I tried with @, then I mixed to double check. none work, apparently there is the hydration to be done but there is no documentation on vue3 page

Comment: This isn"t an answer, this is a comment..